# Check parsing error in .jexl file using java

Tags: java, parsing, jexl

How to check parsing error in .jexl file using java?

The application uses a directory comprising of several .jexl files. 
Some of them experiences parsing error post code merging.

Are there any ways to externally check for the existing parsing error in these files prior to compilation of the entire application. (Using Java)